# Issue with scrollIntoView and focus

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, zend-framework

```
var mediaIdForFocus = '<?php echo $this->mediaIdForFocus; ?>';
if(mediaIdForFocus)
$('#flagimg'+mediaIdForFocus).get(0).scrollIntoView().addClass("selectedMedia"); // highlight class
$('.logoTxt').focus();
```

I am trying to adjust the scroll of a div `$('#flagimg'+mediaIdForFocus)` then give the focus to the element `$('.logoTxt')`

Scroll view is adjusted to the element `$('#flagimg'+mediaIdForFocus)` but, `$('.logoTxt').focus();` is not giving the focus. It happens only on first time. If I refresh the page it is working as expected.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(document).scrollTop(0);` did the trick

Code is given below

```
// for setting the focus to selected media if it is chosen from media page.
var mediaIdForFocus = '<?php echo $this->mediaIdForFocus; ?>';
if(mediaIdForFocus)
   $('#flagimg'+mediaIdForFocus).get(0).scrollIntoView(); // highlight class
$(document).scrollTop(0);
```

Comment: $(document).scrollTop(0); just goes to the top of the page. Your statement above is makening no sense anymore if you would add '$(document).scrollTop(0);'

Comment: @JacobvanLingen van Lingen $('#flagimg'+mediaIdForFocus).get(0).scrollIntoView(); will adjust the scroll bar of $('#flagimg'+mediaIdForFocus) and sets the focus to $('#flagimg'+mediaIdForFocus), then $(document).scrollTop(0); scrolls the entire document to top

Answer (score 27):

To smoothly scroll an element into view and set the focus to it you can do something like

```js
elm.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center'});
elm.focus({preventScroll: true});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is propably the codeline  `$('#flagimg'+mediaIdForFocus).get(0).scrollIntoView().addClass("selectedMedia");`

The `.get(0)` returns the plain element, so the jQuery wrapper is gone. `.addClass()` is a jQuery function, executing jQuery functions at plain elements is not possible.

So first add the class and afterwards scroll the element in your view:
`$('#flagimg'+mediaIdForFocus).addClass("selectedMedia").get(0).scrollIntoView();`